# Increasing the number of Windows Hello attempts to sign in and frequents loads

Tags: windows-hello

OK. So recently I got myself a new Acer Swift 5 weightless laptop. I am very satisfied but I have two issues I want to consult with some experts. Reditors are fine, yes. The product is very fine but have a small issue where the fingerprint scanner is lousy. That way, I can't always pass with Window's greetings when using the fingerprint sensor fingerprint check and is forced to enter a bothersome password (I have a 16 digits lengts password, lol). So, Windows Hello is giving 3 wishes before having you enter your PIN. Can I increase the number of times it is allowing? And please, don't be bothered as to give me marvelous ways to do that as I am a humble (but security concerned) user.

Secondly, I have strange "loadings" in the new computer. This is powered by an i-5 10th gen Intel 1GHZ processor. Very often, I see the mouse indicator with the loading sign (this stupid circle. was easier to understand when it was an hourglass). Because I am not very young and thus have used that many computers, what I am experiencing now I see as abnormal when it shows as if it is loading even when idle. There seems to be no slowdowns though. It is a basic thing because I tried to install a fresh copy of window and it didn't disappear so I guess I won't be able to fix it. But maybe I don't need to?

Answer (score 0):

**For the first issue:** the number of scan attempts is not adjustable. I have the same issue with my own Fingerprint reader.

Suggestion: You have a 4-digit PIN that goes with your Fingerprint.  Use the PIN instead of password. That works.

Also make sure the Fingerprint glass (scan area) is normally clean.

**Second issue:**  The "circle" to show loading / working is now the way Windows works. This does not change either.

So just work around the way things are now done.

I hope this helps you. I have used lots of computers before as well.

Comment: Thanks m8. So you say new computers smmes to load every now and then though it wasn't like this before (I used the mouse indicated that the computer is loading when it needed to do some real loading and not while it is actually idle, I wonder what stands bedhind this.

Also, what is the reason to have a complex password but to include a 4 digits PIN? Is PIN available to those who have a physical access?

Comment: You can use either PIN or Password but not both. PIN should be only known to you so that someone with access will not be able to use the PIN/Fingerprint.  On the circle, numerous things kick it off (updates and scanning for example) and not just one thing.